# what is the big O complexity of the functions involving log

Tags: algorithm, big-o

what is the big O complexity of the function 1005 n^1.75 + 100 n^1.5 + 10nlogn ?

I know that the big O complexity of logn is equal to O(logn)^2) but can't figure out this riddle: 1005 n^1.75 + 100 n^1.5 + 10nlogn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f(n) = 1005 n^1.75 + 100 n^1.5 + 10nlogn`

Now, in O notation, we only need to consider the highest order terms, also constants can be ignored.
Therefore,

`f(n) = n^1.75`

Hence,

`O(f(n)) = O(n^1.75) or O(n^7/4)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just for clarification, in the function: n + nlogn, are you supposed to consider the highest order of 'n' too? or is it going to be something different?

Comment: Yes, whatever the function might be, for O(f(n)) always consider the highest order terms. Hope the answer was helpful.

Comment: Might also be helpful to add an explanation for why `log n` has a lower growth rate than any positive power of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

the complexity of that function is:

```
O(N^(7/4))
```

Comment: could you explain the answer in a step by step formation